# Unable to connect to Mongodb which is on windows server from ubuntu using php

Tags: php, windows, mongodb, ubuntu

I wanted to connect to the **MongoDB** which is installed in windows server from ubuntu using php.
I am trying to connect using the following code but output is nothing even mongoexception is not throwing any error.

```
$mngo = new Mongo("mongodb://192.168.1.119:27017");
$db = $mngo->selectDB('travelmanagement_qa');
```

Can anyone please tell me why i am not able to connect?
Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0):

A few comments:

- Please use `new MongoClient` instead of `new Mongo`.
- This should not output anything at all. You're just selecting a database and assigning it to a variable. Is that your whole code snippet?
- What did you expect the output to be?

To figure out what is actually happening under the hood with connections you can use `MongoLog`. With this functionality you can track down what the driver is doing internally. You'd use it like:

```
MongoLog::setLevel(MongoLog::ALL);
MongoLog::setModule(MongoLog::RS);
MongoLog::setCallback( 'printMsgs' );

function printMsgs($a, $b, $msg)
{
    echo $msg, "\n";
}
```